# How would you go about making this code self modifying to save all passwords entered?

Tags: c++

This is a code that i modified a bit to generate a password and save it with a string for a name and i would like for it to save the passwords to be viewed whenever the code is reopened any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like for it to be able to self modify itself so that i can display and delete the passwords that are generated

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//selectArray is  a utility function that is used to
//randomly generate a integer in the range 1 to 4 (both inclusive)
int selectArray()
{
    // Using malloc() function we are Dynamically allocating memory
    //for a Integer and this function will return a pointer pointing to the allocated memory
    int *j=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    // The content of int pointer j (i.e an address) will be
    //interpreted as an Integer and will be assigned to integer variable i.
    int i=int(j);
    i=i%5;
    if(i==0)
        i++;
    return i;
}

//getKey() is another utility function that is used to randomly generate
//an integer in the range 0 to 25 (both inclusive)
int getKey()
{
    // Using malloc() function we are Dynamically allocating memory for an
    //Integer and this function will return a pointer pointing to the allocated memory
    int *i=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    // The content of int pointer i (i.e an address) will be interpreted as
    // an Integer and will be assigned to integer variable key.
    int key=int(i);
    key=key%26;
    return key;
}
char generate_password(int length)
{
    //Intializing result string password as NULL.
    string password="";

    //Strings whose characters will be used to build password
    string alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string ALPHABET="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string s_symbol="!@#$%&";
    string number="0123456789";
    string str, strresult;
    string str1 = "=";


    //intializing local variables
    int key,count_alphabet=0,count_ALPHABET=0,count_number=0,count_s_symbol=0;

    //Count will store the length of the password being created,initially this will be zero(0)
    int count=0;
    while(count<length)
    {
        // selectArray() function will return a number 1 to 4
        // and will use to select one of the above defined string
        //(i.e alphabet or ALPHABET or s_symbol or number )
        // 1 is for string alphabet
        // 2 is for string ALPHABET
        // 3 is for string number
        // and 4 is for string s_symbol


        int k=selectArray();

        //for the first character of password it is mentioned that ,it should be a letter
        // so the string that should be selected is either alphabet or ALPHABET (i.e 1 or 2)
        // following if condition will take care of it.
        if(count==0)
        {
            k=k%3;
            if(k==0)
                k++;
        }
        switch(k)
        {
            case 1:
            // following if condition will check if minimum requirement of alphabet
            // character has been fulfilled or not
            // incase it has been fulfilled and minimum requirements of other
            // characters is still left then it will break ;
            if((count_alphabet==2)&&(count_number==0||count_ALPHABET==0||count_ALPHABET==1||count_s_symbol==0))
                break;

            key=getKey();
            password=password+alphabet[key];
            count_alphabet++;
            count++;
            break;

            case 2:
            // following if condition will check if minimum requirement of
            // ALPHABET character has been fulfilled or not
            // incase it has been fulfilled and minimum requirements of
            // other characters is still left then it will break ;
            if((count_ALPHABET==2)&&(count_number==0||count_alphabet==0||count_alphabet==1||count_s_symbol==0))
                break;
            key=getKey();
            password=password+ALPHABET[key];
            count_ALPHABET++;
            count++;
            break;

            case 3:
            // following if condition will check if minimum requirement
            // of Numbers  has been fulfilled or not
            // incase it has been fulfilled and minimum requirements of
            // other characters is still left then it will break ;
            if((count_number==1)&&(count_alphabet==0||count_alphabet==1||count_ALPHABET==1||count_ALPHABET==0||count_s_symbol==0))
                break;

            key=getKey();
            key=key%10;
            password=password+number[key];
            count_number++;
            count++;
            break;

            case 4:
            // following if condition will check if minimum requirement of
            // Special symbol character has been fulfilled or not
            // incase it has been fulfilled and minimum requirements of
            // other characters is still left then it will break ;
            if((count_s_symbol==1)&&(count_alphabet==0||count_alphabet==1||count_ALPHABET==0||count_ALPHABET==1||count_number==0))
                break;

            key=getKey();
            key=key%6;
            password=password+s_symbol[key];
            count_s_symbol++;
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter name for password: ";
    cin >> str;

    cout << "" << strresult;
    cout << "\n-----------------------------\n";
    cout << "         Password             \n";
    cout << "------------------------------\n\n";
    cout << " " <<  password;


    cout << "\nPassword: " << str << " = " << password;
    cout <<"\n\nPress any key continue \n";

}
int main()
{
    int opt,length;
    string str, strresult;
    string str1;
    //Menu
    do
    {
        cout << "\n-----------------------------\n";
        cout << "  Random Password Generator\n";
        cout << "------------------------------\n\n";
        cout << "    1. Generate Password" << "\n";
        cout << "    2. Exit" << "\n\n";
        cout << "Press key 1 to Generate Password and key 2 to display saved passwords : ";
        cin >> opt;

        switch(opt)
        {
            case 1:



            // Length should not exceed 100 , program should show error if it exceeds



            generate_password(10);


            break;

            default:
            // If invalid option is choosen by user it will also show error
            if(opt!=2)
            {
                printf("\nInvalid choice\n");
                printf("Please Press ( 1 ) to generate password and ( 2 ) to display saved passwords.\n");
                cout <<"Press any key to try again \n";
                getchar();
            }
            break;
        }
    }while(opt!=2);
        cout << "" << strresult;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but good reading: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Also, don't include the C header `stdio.h`. Include `cstdio` if you need it at all for this.

Comment: Also unrelated, but use the [random library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) to generate random numbers instead of relying on random locations of heap-allocations. Btw, all of those "random numbers" leak memory. And they may cause integer overflow.

Comment: Do you really want to make the code self modifying (which is not easy). Why not just store the passwords seperately to the program? Or better still store password hashes seperately.

Comment: Simpler would be to use some additional resource file instead of using executable file (and antivirus should warn when exe is modified)...

Comment: Save the passwords to a file that you read whenever the program starts. Passwords should however never be saved in a format that would let anyone be able to read the password but for a toy project it may be ok.

Comment: Most modern operating systems load executables into memory and mark memory containing executable code as "execute-only" which - among other things - prevents the executable code being modified. The executable file itself is also often locked to prevent modification while being executed. These behaviours are DELIBERATELY DESIGNED to prevent things like self-modifying executables that can compromise system stability. Practically, a common use-case for self-modifying executables is malware. Better to use a separate file, with appropriately encrypted content, so store passwords.